# App crashes on some devices

Tags: ios, crash, push-notification

My app is launched and its crashing on some devices not all i have flurry logs as well which are confusing, they suggest its crashing in this function.

This function is called when the app launches (it crashes immediately)
Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
- (void) setupForPushNotifications {
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *readAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
readAction.identifier = @"READ_IDENTIFIER";
readAction.title = @"Read";
readAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground;
readAction.destructive = NO;
readAction.authenticationRequired = YES;

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *ignoreAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
ignoreAction.identifier = @"IGNORE_IDENTIFIER";
ignoreAction.title = @"Ignore";
ignoreAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
ignoreAction.destructive = NO;
ignoreAction.authenticationRequired = NO;

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *deleteAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
deleteAction.identifier = @"DELETE_IDENTIFIER";
deleteAction.title = @"Delete";
deleteAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground;
deleteAction.destructive = YES;
deleteAction.authenticationRequired = YES;

UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *messageCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
messageCategory.identifier = @"MESSAGE_CATEGORY";
[messageCategory setActions:@[readAction, ignoreAction, deleteAction] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
[messageCategory setActions:@[readAction, deleteAction] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];

NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:messageCategory];

UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:categories];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
```

}

===========================================

## And here is a portion of the crash logs

```
    Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x396631f0
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x2e91bf0b <redacted> + 130
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x390aece7 _objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2e8552eb -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 418
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2e85ec61 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 44
4   RunnerXiOS                          0x000b6a83 -[AppController setupForPushNotifications] + 482
5   RunnerXiOS                          0x000b5a57 -[AppController application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 1222
6   UIKit                               0x311bacc1 <redacted> + 276
7   UIKit                               0x311ba613 <redacted> + 1610
8   UIKit                               0x311b4cc9 <redacted> + 720
9   UIKit                               0x31150c97 <redacted> + 3550
10  UIKit                               0x3114fdf9 <redacted> + 72
11  UIKit                               0x311b4405 <redacted> + 616
12  GraphicsServices                    0x337adb55 <redacted> + 608
13  GraphicsServices                    0x337ad73f <redacted> + 34
14  CoreFoundation                      0x2e8e6847 <redacted> + 34
15  CoreFoundation                      0x2e8e67e3 <redacted> + 346
16  CoreFoundation                      0x2e8e4faf <redacted> + 1406
17  CoreFoundation                      0x2e84f769 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
18  CoreFoundation                      0x2e84f54b _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
19  UIKit                               0x311b362b <redacted> + 762
20  UIKit                               0x311ae891 _UIApplicationMain + 1136
21  RunnerXiOS                          0x000cf627 -[CCAtlasNode setQuadsToDraw:] + 90
22  RunnerXiOS                          0x00072218 __mh_execute_header + 21016
```

Comment: Are any of the devices running iOS < 8 ?

Comment: Looks like it's telling you that `readAction` is `nil`.

Comment: Yes u think this could be related to ios version?

Comment: readAction its clearly not nil and how could it be nil for only a few devices and not all?

Answer (score 1):

Interactive notification works from IOS 8.0